# Understanding Weird Relationship Between Hamming Weights

Tags: probability-distributions, finite-fields, binary, covariance

I have two binary "mapping" matrices $\delta_0$ and $\delta_1$

$
\delta_0 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0\\
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0\\
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0\\
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0\\
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0\\
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0\\
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0\\
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$

$\delta_1 =   \begin{bmatrix}
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0\\
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0\\
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\\
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0\\
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0\\
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0\\
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0\\
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
  \end{bmatrix}$

The least significant bit is in the bottom right. The most significant bit is in the top left.

Their purpose is to map binary values in a finite field GF($2^8$) into another. This involves multiplying each possible element by each matrix.

I map the elements 0-255 for both matrices. Computed using $\delta_i\times x$ mod 2 for $x$ 0-255 in binary. I know have two matrices which contain 256 "mapped" values.

I take the a hamming weight of each mapped value. This computes the number of '1' bits in each mapped entry. I keep it in order.

I then take the co-variance of the hamming weights and I find it equals zero.

Ok, that particular order results in a covariance zero.

But now I keep the hamming weight array of $\delta_0 \times x$ mod 2 the same. And for the second mapping I do $\delta_1 \times (x\oplus c)$ mod 2. Where $c$ is a constant 8 bit value and $\oplus$ is the XOR operator. I take the hamming weight of these mapped values.

I calculate the co-variance of the hamming weight arrays and it is zero again. For every possible 8 bit value of $c$ I find the co-variance is zero.

Adding a constant $r$ doesn't change the distribution of the hamming weights but I would expect the co-variance to change now that the order is different.

I am kind of lost why the co-variance remains zero. I believe that co-variance is heavily dependent on order, so I assume that add $c$ would change the order enough to cause the co-variance to fluctuate. Is there something I m missing?

Comment: Elements of finite fields don't have least significant or most significant bits. And I don't understand how $GF(256)$ fits into this scheme at all.  All I see is two 8x8 matrices with entries in $GF(2)$. Sure you can multiply (from the left) 8x1 column vectors of bits with those matrices, and calculate some correlations. But what does any of that to do with $GF(256)$? You lost me somewhere.

Comment: If the matrices are invertible, then going through all the numbers $0-255$ will simply shuffle them; adding $c$ will not make any difference. The covariance is the sum of products over all the numbers, hence it is the same in both cases.

Comment: Sorry they are elements in $GF(2^8)$ I edited my question